# Get page number to create index

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a list of phrases in Excel and need to determine what page those phrases can be found on in a Word document in order to then create an index for the book. I found the following VBA code online, but I get an error on the line that should be returning the page number (inside the If statement, when true). I don't have much experience with using VBA in Word, so I'm having a hard time determining what I should be doing differently.

```
Sub PageNumbers()
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wordapp.Visible = True
    wordapp.Activate
    wordapp.Documents.Open "WORD DOCUMENT"
    Set findRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100")
    For Each findCell In findRange.Cells
        Set rngFound = wordapp.ActiveDocument.Range
        With rngFound.Find
            .Text = findCell.Value
            .Execute
        End With
        If rngFound.Find.Found Then
            findCell.Offset(columnOffset:=1) = rngFound.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Else
            findCell.Offset(columnOffset:=1) = findCell.Value
        End If
    Next findCell
    wordapp.Quit

    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Set findCell = Nothing
    Set findRange = Nothing
    Set wordapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Word has a built in feature to [Create and update an index](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-and-update-an-index-cc502c71-a605-41fd-9a02-cda9d14bf073).

Comment: `wdActiveEndPageNumber` is a Word VBA constant. Excel does not know what it is. You either need to set a reference to Word (Tools | References) or use the value of the constant (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.WdInformation)

Comment: Word can do this automatically if you save your workbook as a document laid out as an index concordance. See, for example: & https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/46885-advanced-index-query.html.